# Cross-browser ready new line counter in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, count, trim

I got 2 questions:

- My function looks like that

  `function count() {
      var value =  ids.val();
      return (value == '') ? 0 : value.replace(/\s,?|,$/g, '').split(/\r\n|\r|\n/).length;
  }`

What I wanna do is, to skip whitespaces and count all new lines
For ex:

```
85
96
75
<whitespace>
76
```

count() must return 4 not 5. How can I modify my function?

- How to convert line break seperated words/numbers to comma seperated content?

For ex:

```
85
96
75<whitespace>
<whitespace>
76
```

I want to trim all whitespaces and convert whole content into something like that `85,96,75,76`. How can I do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be `.filter($.trim).map($.trim)`, which first removes any whitespace entries, and then cleans the remaining entries by removing surrounding spaces: http://jsfiddle.net/BtLzf/1/.

```
var vals = ids.val()
             .split(/\r\n|\r|\n/)
             .filter($.trim)
             .map($.trim);

vals.length; // 4
vals.join(); // 85,96,75,76
```

`.filter`/`.map` are ES5 which means you'll need a shim for older browsers.

Comment: @epic_syntax: What's the problem? Just make a function `count` which returns `vals.length`.

Comment: There is one problem. I have autopost function which checks for count every 1 sec. if(count() === 10){ ajaxpost! } Barcode reader enters digits one by one: it adds new line after each scan. So can we modify this function to wait for new line and count? I mean if 8 and new line then count must return 1

Comment: are you there?..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9540892/wait-for-new-line-and-count/9540987#9540987

Comment: @epic_syntax: With 8 lines and a newline `count` wouldn't return `10` here because the newlines are filtered out...

Comment: Return what? I really can't get a picture of what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: For ex

if i type `8`
Function must return 0 (currently it returns 1 directly after typing any value)
if i type
8
<newline>
Function must return 1 . and so on

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8462/discussion-between-epic-syntax-and-pimvdb)

Answer (score 0):

I think that you will need to do a loop for checking the length of each line, because in this case you're getting the number of end-of-line characters, which is 5 even if the line is empty... Getting this iterator you can also get the comma-list

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using a regex pattern that cleans things up a bit better.
Perhaps:

> ^(\d+)\s?$

```
$(function(){
    var matches = $('#txtInput').text().match(/^(\d+)\s?$/mg);
    $('#txtResult').text(matches.join(','));
});​
```

Working Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/mZ97L/

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this?

```
// Count of items in the list.
function count(){
    var list = delimitedList();
    return list.split(",").length;
}

// Get list separated by comma.
function delimitedList(){
    var value = ids.val();
    return value.replace(/\s+/g, ",");
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wT23h/2/