# Wait for new line and count

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, count

My function looks like that

```
function count() {
   var value =  ids.val();
    return (value == '') ? 0 : value.split(/\r\n|\r|\n/).filter($.trim).map($.trim).length;
}
```

There is one problem. I have autopost function which checks for `count()` every 1 sec.

```
if(count() === 10){ ajaxpost! }
```

Barcode reader enters digits one by one: it adds new line after each scan.

How to modify this function to wait for new line and count?

For ex

```
8
```

Function must return 0 (currently it returns 1 directly after typing any value)

```
8
<newline>
```

Function must return 1

Answer (score 0):

```
function count() {
   var value =  ids.val();
   if(!value)
       return 0;
   var len = value.split(/\r\n|\r|\n/).filter($.trim).map($.trim).length;
   return len < 10 ? 0 : len;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can actually modify the barcode scanner to not give the new line, but else you can use the replace and remove the new lines. something like

```
myStr.replace(/[\r\n]/,'')
```

**EDIT**
let me explain better:

```
return (value == '') ? 0 : value.split(/\r\n|\r|\n/).filter($.trim).map($.trim).replace(/[\r\n]/,'').length;
```

This will remove the new lines s you wont have

```
8
<newline>
```

Comment: omg... you have not understood my question at all. it must return value every time if there is empty new line..

Comment: ooohh.. you need the number of lines, so `8` `<newline>` returns 1, but `8` returns 0, and `8` `9` `<newline>` returns 2 .. correct ?

Comment: It doesn't work at all... Once more: it must return every time if there is empty new line..